# keras - cannot concatenate Embedding and CategoryEncoding layers

Tags: tensorflow, keras

## Problem

Following the [GCP Vertex AI example](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/mlops-with-vertex-ai/blob/main/02-experimentation.ipynb) with the code below.

```
    for key in input_layers:
        feature_name = features.original_name(key)
        if feature_name in features.EMBEDDING_CATEGORICAL_FEATURES:
            vocab_size = feature_vocab_sizes[feature_name]
            embedding_size = features.EMBEDDING_CATEGORICAL_FEATURES[feature_name]
            
            embedding_output = keras.layers.Embedding(
                input_dim=vocab_size + 1,
                output_dim=embedding_size,
                name=f"{key}_embedding",
            )(input_layers[key])

            print(f"Shape of embed layer [{key}] has None [{embedding_output.shape}] output_dim is {embedding_size}")
            
            layers.append(embedding_output)
        elif feature_name in features.ONEHOT_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_NAMES:
            vocab_size = feature_vocab_sizes[feature_name]
            onehot_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding(
                max_tokens=vocab_size,
                output_mode="binary",
                name=f"{key}_onehot",
            )(input_layers[key])

            onehot_layer = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
                num_tokens=vocab_size, 
                output_mode="one_hot",
                name=f"{key}_onehot",
            )(input_layers[key])
            
            print(f"Shape of one hot layer [{key}] has None [{onehot_layer.shape}]")
                      
            layers.append(onehot_layer)
        elif feature_name in features.NUMERICAL_FEATURE_NAMES:
            numeric_layer = tf.expand_dims(input_layers[key], -1)

            print(f"Shape of numeric layer [{key}] has None [{numeric_layer.shape}]")
                      
            layers.append(numeric_layer)
        else:
            pass

    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    # Concatenate Embedding and CategoryEncoding layers fails
    #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    joined = keras.layers.Concatenate(name="combines_inputs")(layers)
```

The code causes the error of not being able to concatenate layers.

```
Shape of embed layer [trip_month_xf] has None [(None, 2)]
Shape of embed layer [trip_day_xf] has None [(None, 4)]
Shape of one hot layer [trip_day_of_week_xf] has None [(7,)]
Shape of embed layer [trip_hour_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of numeric layer [trip_seconds_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of numeric layer [trip_miles_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of one hot layer [payment_type_xf] has None [(5,)]
Shape of embed layer [pickup_grid_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of embed layer [dropoff_grid_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of numeric layer [euclidean_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of embed layer [loc_cross_xf] has None [(None, 10)]

ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concatenation axis. Received: input_shape=[(None, 2), (None, 4), (7,), (None, 3), (None, 1), (None, 1), (5,), (None, 3), (None, 3), (None, 1), (None, 10)]
```

## Question

What is the cause and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

## Cause

`keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding` layer generates the shape `(N, )`.

Tried to reshape to `(None, N)` but did not work

```
from keras.layers.core import Reshape

onehot_layer = Reshape((-1, vocab_size))(onehot_layer)
----------
ValueError: Exception encountered when calling layer "reshape_13" (type Reshape).

Dimension size must be evenly divisible by 49 but is 7 for '{{node reshape_13/Reshape}} = Reshape[T=DT_FLOAT, Tshape=DT_INT32](Placeholder, reshape_13/Reshape/shape)' with input shapes: [7], [3] and with input tensors computed as partial shapes: input[1] = [7,?,7].

Call arguments received:
  • inputs=tf.Tensor(shape=(7,), dtype=float32)
```

## Fix

Use `tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding`.

```
        elif feature_name in features.ONEHOT_CATEGORICAL_FEATURE_NAMES:
            vocab_size = feature_vocab_sizes[feature_name]
            # onehot_layer = keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing.CategoryEncoding(
            #     max_tokens=vocab_size,
            #     output_mode="binary",
            #     name=f"{key}_onehot",
            # )(input_layers[key])
            onehot_layer = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding(
                num_tokens=vocab_size, 
                output_mode="one_hot",
                name=f"{key}_onehot",
            )(input_layers[key])
```

Result:

```
Shape of embed layer [trip_month_xf] has None [(None, 2)]
Shape of embed layer [trip_day_xf] has None [(None, 4)]
Shape of one hot layer [trip_day_of_week_xf] has None [(None, 7)]
Shape of embed layer [trip_hour_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of numeric layer [trip_seconds_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of numeric layer [trip_miles_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of one hot layer [payment_type_xf] has None [(None, 5)]
Shape of embed layer [pickup_grid_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of embed layer [dropoff_grid_xf] has None [(None, 3)]
Shape of numeric layer [euclidean_xf] has None [(None, 1)]
Shape of embed layer [loc_cross_xf] has None [(None, 10)]
```

## References

- [What does an Input layer of shape=(None,) or (None,12) actually mean?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/54159)

> In tf.keras, a None dimension means that it can be any scalar number, so that you use this model to infer on an arbitrarily long input. This dimension does not affect the size of the network, it just denotes that you are free to select the length (number of samples) of your input during testing.

- [ValueError: Tried to convert 'shape' to a tensor and failed. Error: None values not supported. #1070](https://github.com/matterport/Mask_RCNN/issues/1070)

> If you want to use tf.keras or from tensorflow import keras, all you have to do to fix this error is replace the first value (s[1] == None) in the tf.keras.layers.Reshape function with -1:
>
> Replace with the following code:
>
> ```
> mrcnn_bbox = layers.Reshape((-1, num_classes, 4), name="mrcnn_bbox")(x)
> ```

- [How to concatenate embeddings with variable length inputs in Keras?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58311682/how-to-concatenate-embeddings-with-variable-length-inputs-in-keras)

> ```
> modifier_input_ = Input(shape=(None,), name='modifier_type_in')
> ...
> statistics_inputs =[Input(shape=(None, len(statistics),), name='statistics')] # Input(shape=(1,))
> ```

- [How to add One-Hot Encoding layer to Tensorflow model?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65646881/how-to-add-one-hot-encoding-layer-to-tensorflow-model)

> ```
> numerical_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(2,), dtype=tf.float32)
>  
> categorical_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32)
> encoded = tf.keras.layers.CategoryEncoding( num_tokens=3, output_mode="one_hot")(categorical_input)
>
> concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([numerical_input, encoded])
> ```